# how to structure multiple levels in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

so I'm looking to create the following structure in firestore

```
code_table: [
   "GIM": [
       {
          "label":"assement",
           "codes": ["A001A","A002A",...]
       },
       {
          "label":"consults",
           "codes": ["A001A","A002A",...]
       }
    ....
]
```

Between the documents and the collections I can't seem to be able to get this into the firebase firestore using the web ui (Just creating the test data) in such a way that I can actually query it using the flutter sdk

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are documents and what are collections in this structure? It might also be useful if you show what you tried.

Comment: I'm newer to firebase, so I think what I'm trying to create is a code table document, a collection of specialties with a collection of objects.

Comment: Is `GIM` in the above JSON a subcollection under the `code_table` document then?

Comment: Yes, it will be a collection of specialties

Comment: OK. So that means that the elements in the `GIM` array are documents in that subcollection of the `code_table` document. What problem do you have creating this structure in the Firebase console?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to string multiple collections along, it only lets me add primitive types, not another collection

Comment: Since I can't figure out what the problem is that you're having, I created the structure on one of my own databases, and described what I did in an answer below. If that doesn't help you solve it, describe what you're doing in a similar way in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step, here's how I create a top-level collection, a `code_table` document, a `GIM` subcollection under that document, and then a document in there.

1. Create a top-level collection with a `code_table` document in there.
   [image]
2. Select the `code_table` document, and click <kbd>Add collection</kbd>
   [image]

   This creates a subcollection under the `code_table` document in the top-level collection.
3. Name the collection `GIM` and click <kbd>Next</kbd>
   [image]
4. Click the <kbd>Auto-ID</kbd> link to generate a document ID, and enter the fields for your first document in the nested collection. [image]

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>
5. Now you have a top-level collection, a `code_table` document in there, a `GIM` subcollection under that document, and a first document in there. 
   [image]